# Ajax request to another controller in codeigniter not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I have a Login/logout method located in my home controller. There are username and password textboxes on all the pages which are generated by different controllers.

I've a common jquery file for all my views which uses ajax to post the username and password from any of the pages to the Home controller Login/Logout method. But this does not seem to work as those pages are being generated by different controllers and not the Home controller. When I check firebug I see the url mentioned in the Ajax script is being appended to the controller of that page and no actual redirection takes place.

I've seen that it is usually recommended to use a self made helper in such scenarios. But I'm not sure how can that be used via jquery ajax.

Home controller

```
                function validate_login_user()
            {
                    $this->load->model('model');

                    if ($this->sristi_model->validate_login())
                    {
                        $data = array (
                            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                            'is_logged_in' => true
                        );
                        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                        $this->load->view('includes/logged_in.php');
                        //return true;
                    }else{
                        $this->load->view('includes/loginerror.php');
                        //return true;
                    }
            }
```

The javascript

```
    $('#sitelogin').on('click', '.login', function(){
        var username = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#password').val();
        if (username == "" || password == ""){
            $('#error').fadeIn(200).delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
            return false;
        }else if(username !== undefined && password !== undefined)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"home/validate_login_user",
                type:'POST',
                data:{username:username,password:password},
                cache:false,
                success:function(msg){
                    $('#sitelogin').html(msg).hide().fadeIn(800);
                    $('#loginerror').delay(2000).fadeOut(1000);
                }
            });
            return false;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
```

When I try to login through the Product controller I get this in Firebug

```
URL: POST validate_login_user
localhost/ci/product/categories/localhost/ci/home/validate_login_user

Status: 500 Internal Server Error

Domain: localhost

Size: 1.6 KB

Remote IP: [::1]:80
```

Let me know if you find something...

Comment: Can you provide... any code?

Comment: Its more of a conceptual question hence I thought of asking it without the code. Which part of the code would you like to have?

Comment: The output from firebug, the home controller code for login/logout, the javascript code for performing the request. Maybe even the html for the login form.

Comment: I've added the code, let me know if you see something.

Comment: i do not understand why are there 3 downvotes....?????. Please explain else don't play around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was somehow able to see this answer in my notifications but I don't see it on this page. Preceding the ajax url with a slash did the job and now everything is working fine.

Thanks to whoever commented that.